# Alternatives to "WHERE IN (...)"?

Tags: mysql

I've got a project under way which has gotten a little out of hand (in terms of being well organized and thought out) as it started very small and has grown quite quickly.

Anyhow, we have a system which tracks user activity, records UUIDS and also specific contact activity which we use to generate information as to exactly what the customer has been viewing on the site.  Pretty standard.  Anyhow, its gotten a bit complex and slow and I am hoping for some help optimizing the query.

I'm sure there is a much better way to do it (using JOINS perhaps) than I am currently using, but I can't seem to get my head around it.  Some help would be appreciated.  Associated info is below.

Thanks.

**Table: visitor_activity**

```
CREATE TABLE `visitor_activity` (
 `vaid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uuid` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`vaid`),
 KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
 KEY `ip_address` (`ip_address`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=70134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table: contact_uuids**

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_uuids` (
 `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `uuid` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`,`uuid`),
 KEY `contact_id` (`contact_id`),
 KEY `uuid` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table: contact_log**

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_log` (
 `contact_log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `action` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `performed_by` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`contact_log_id`),
 KEY `contact_id` (`contact_id`),
 KEY `ip_address` (`ip_address`),
 KEY `performed_by` (`performed_by`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9017 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Current SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT   DISTINCT(`va`.`vaid`),
         `va`.`datetime`,
         `va`.`uuid`,
         `va`.`ip_address`,
         `va`.`url`
FROM     `visitor_activity` `va`
WHERE    `va`.`uuid` IN (SELECT `uuid` FROM `contact_uuids` `cu` WHERE `cu`.`contact_id` = '1') ||
         `va`.`ip_address` IN (SELECT DISTINCT(`ip_address`) FROM `contact_log` `cl` WHERE `cl`.`contact_id` = '1' && `performed_by` = 'Contact')
ORDER BY `va`.`datetime` DES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your query in two selects to join different tables, and then use `union` to join all the data. The query might look like this:

```
(SELECT   DISTINCT(`va`.`vaid`),
     `va`.`datetime`,
     `va`.`uuid`,
     `va`.`ip_address`,
     `va`.`url`
FROM     `visitor_activity` `va`,`contact_uuids` `cu`
WHERE    `va`.`uuid`=`cu`.`uuid`
and `cu`.`contact_id` = '1')
UNION
(SELECT   DISTINCT(`va`.`vaid`),
     `va`.`datetime`,
     `va`.`uuid`,
     `va`.`ip_address`,
     `va`.`url`
FROM  `visitor_activity` `va`,`contact_log` `cl`
where `va`.`ip_address` = `cl`.`ip_address` 
and `cl`.`contact_id` = '1' and `performed_by` = 'Contact')
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I should have been able to see that.  Cheers man.